# Problemas para convertir un campo alias en un campo real y físico en la base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta que me funciona perfecto, me da el resultado en una campo alias.

Necesito que ese resultado sea un campo real y físico en la base de datos y que se quede almacenado.

Me explico mejor: necesito que un campo de mi base de datos almacene el resultado de esa consulta.

Ésta es la consulta:

```
SELECT SUM(`f350_vlr1_debito`) AS TOTAL_DEBITO, 
SUM(`f350_vlr1_credito`) AS TOTAL_CREDITOS, 
`f350_id_escenario` AS ESCENARIO, 
`f350_mes` AS MES, 
substring(`f350_id_cuenta`,1,2) AS GRUPO, 
`f350_año` AS AÑO 
FROM t350_plan_pres_movto 
WHERE f350_id_cuenta 
LIKE '52%' AND 
f350_id_escenario = 2 AND 
f350_mes = 6 AND 
f350_año = 2022
```

Como ven el campo `TOTAL_DEBITO` y `TOTAL_CREDITO` me entregan el resultado, pero en la tabla `VALORES_REALES` tengo los campos `TOTAL_DEBITO` y `TOTAL_CREDITO`. Pero no logro que el resultado se almacene en esos campos. Soy nuevo en esto y es posible que sea muy sencillo pero lo ignoro, agradecería mucho la ayuda de ustedes.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para poder ayudarte mejor necesitaríamos conocer el esquema de las tablas (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <tabla>`). Imagino que lo que quieres es hacer un `INSERT INTO <tabla>` de los valores obtenidos con ese `SELECT`, ¿me equivoco?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de la tabla Valores_Reales

Comment: Y dónde está la parte en la que intentas hacer un insert con esos datos?

Comment: Buenas tardes, la verdad no se usar esa instruccion "insert" como les informe soy nuevo y completamente autodidacta, si me indicaran como funciona el comando insert, les agradeceria.

Comment: Si eres autodidacta deberías comenzar por consultar el manual de MySQL: [INSERT ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html). También te recomiendo cualquier curso de SQL, ya que en la mayoría se explican este tipo de consultas SQL. Por cierto, existe otra solución que sería crear una vista con la información que necesitas, para no duplicar datos: [CREATE VIEW Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html). Las vistas también están cubiertas por la mayoría de tutoriales de SQL, aunque podría considerarse algo más avanzado.

Answer (score 2):

Amigos ya encontre la solucion, como les informe todo esto que he hecho hasta ahora a sido a punta de tutoriales, bueno la situacion era, como escribio el amigo Alfabravo faltaba el INSERT INTO, este es el codigo:

```
INSERT INTO totales_grupos (grupo_11)
SELECT SUM(`f350_vlr1_debito`)
WHERE f350_id_cuenta LIKE '52%' AND f350_id_escenario = 2 AND f350_mes = 6 AND f350_año = 2022
```

Gracias a todos.